# broccoli-config-replace does not work with the configuration given

Tags: javascript, broccolijs

I'm trying to use [broccoli-config-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/broccoli-config-replace) unsuccessfully. What I would like to do is replacing a placeholder in my `index.html` and see it in the browser by executing `broccoli serve`

The interesting part of my Brocfile.js is this one:

```
var index_html = new ConfigReplace(app, './', {
    // A list of files to parse:
    files: [
        'index.html',
    ],
    configPath: 'replacements.json',
    outputPath: 'production/',
    patterns: [{
        match: /\{\{SRC_REQUIRE\}\}/g,
        replacement: function(config) { return config.SRC_REQUIRE; }
    }]
});

module.exports = index_html;
```

but when I run `broccoli serve` what I get is this warning and nothing appears by pointing my browser to `localhost:4200`:

```
$ broccoli serve

Serving on http://localhost:4200

Warning: failed to stat tmp/config_replace-input_base_path-5qF5n457.tmp/1/tmp/config_replace-input_base_path-5qF5n457.tmp/1/tmp/config_replace-input_base_path-5qF5n457.tmp/1/tmp/config_replace-input_base_path-5qF5n457.tmp/1/tmp/config_replace-input_base_path-5qF5n457.tmp/1/tmp/config_replace-input_base_path-5qF5n457.tmp/1/tmp/config_replace-input_base_path-5qF5n457.tmp/1/tmp/config_replace-input_base_path-5qF5n457.tmp/1/tmp/config_replace-input_base_path-5qF5n457.tmp/1/tmp/config_replace-input_base_path-5qF5n457.tmp/1/tmp/config_replace-input_base_path-5qF5n457.tmp/1/tmp/config_replace-input_base_path-5qF5n457.tmp/1/tmp/config_replace-input_base_path-5qF5n457.tmp/1/tmp/config_replace-input_base_path-5qF5n457.tmp/1/tmp/config_replace-input_base_path-5qF5n457.tmp/1/tmp/config_replace-input_base_path-5qF5n457.tmp/1/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/regenerator/node_modules/defs/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/center-align/node_modules/align-text/node_modules/kind-of/README.md
Segmentation fault: 11
```

nice segfault huh? I guess what I've written is not that OK, but the documentation is very lacking. Can anybody suggest me the right configuration to accomplish this simple task? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to get what I want, but I think the plugin still needs some development. Here is the right configuration:

```
var index_html = new ConfigReplace(appHtml, 'conf', {
    // A list of files to parse:
    files: [
        '/production/index.html'
    ],
    configPath: 'replacements.json',
    patterns: [{
        match: /\{\{SRC_REQUIRE\}\}/g,
        replacement: function(config) { return config.SRC_REQUIRE; }
    }]
});
```

Some facts I've noted:

- The configuration node must be a directory. Root is not allowed, so I had to place my `replacements.json` in a subfolder (`/conf`)
- The `outputPath` option seems not to be considered. I omitted it and used a `pickFile` before in order to create a tree with the right structure I wanted. Then I passed the tree to `ConfigReplace` (the `appHtml` you see in the configuration I pasted above)
- Lack of documentation is a bad pal for adopting broccoli happily. I'm confident though.